# Functional test with PHPUnit / Symfony

Tags: beginner, php, phpunit

I am trying to test my first functional tests. I would like to know if my functional test is well done, or if the structure of it is not optimal.

Any advice will be useful to me. As I said, I just started writing functional tests, so I have major doubts about my test method which regroups all of a sudden or should it separate?

```
<?php

namespace Api\Tests\Post;

require_once __DIR__.'/../../../vendor/autoload.php';

use Api\Util\Error;
use Silex\Application;
use Silex\WebTestCase;

use Symfony\Component\Debug\ExceptionHandler;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class UserTest extends WebTestCase
{
/**
 * Basic, application-wide functional test inspired by Symfony best practices.
 * Simply checks that all application URLs load successfully.
 * During test execution, this method is called for each URL returned by the provideUrls method.
 *
 * @dataProvider provideUrls
 * @param $url
 */
public function testPageIsSuccessful($url)
{
    $password   = '%sZ69%$%C5sRz4_5Od$46#5';

    /**
     * Create user with just field required
     */
    $client     = $this->createClient();

    $randomName = rand(1000, 999999);

    $client->request(
        'POST',
        $url,
        array(),
        array(),
        Error::$header,
        '{
            "email":"test+'.$randomName.'@Test.com",
            "password":"'.$password.'",
            "gender":"m",
            "firstName":"Test",
            "lastName":"'.$randomName.'"
        }'
    );

    $object = json_decode($client->getResponse()->getContent(), false);

    $this->assertNotNull($object);
    $this->assertTrue(is_object($object));
    $this->assertEquals($randomName, $object->lastName);
    $this->assertEquals(Response::HTTP_OK, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode(), $client->getResponse()->getContent());


    /**
     * Create user with all field
     */
    $client     = $this->createClient();

    $randomName = rand(1000, 999999);

    $client->request(
        'POST',
        $url,
        array(),
        array(),
        Error::$header,
        '{
            "email":"test2+'.$randomName.'@Test.com",
            "password":"'.$password.'",
            "gender":"m",
            "firstName":"Test",
            "lastName":"'.$randomName.'",
            "image":null,
            "address":null,
            "enabled":1,
            "locked":0,
            "role":["ROLE_ANDROID"],
            "content":"Une description complète sur cette personne",
            "birthday":"1991-06-12",
            "facebookId":null,
            "avatar":null,
            "phone":"0601020304",
            "profession":"Robot",
            "iHostWith":null
        }'
    );

    $object = json_decode($client->getResponse()->getContent(), false);

    $this->assertNotNull($object);
    $this->assertTrue(is_object($object));
    $this->assertEquals($randomName, $object->lastName);
    $this->assertEquals(Response::HTTP_OK, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode(), $client->getResponse()->getContent());



    /**
     * Create user with birthday not good
     */
    $client     = $this->createClient();

    $randomName = rand(1000, 999999);

    $client->request(
        'POST',
        $url,
        array(),
        array(),
        Error::$header,
        '{
            "email":"test3+'.$randomName.'@Test.com",
            "password":"'.$password.'",
            "gender":"m",
            "firstName":"Test",
            "lastName":"'.$randomName.'",
            "image":null,
            "address":null,
            "enabled":1,
            "locked":0,
            "role":["ROLE_ANDROID"],
            "content":"Une description complète sur cette personne",
            "birthday":"2001-06-15",
            "facebookId":null,
            "avatar":null,
            "phone":"0601020304",
            "profession":"Robot",
            "iHostWith":null
        }'
    );

    $object = json_decode($client->getResponse()->getContent(), false);

    $this->assertEquals(Error::USER_AGE_MIN_REQUIRED, $object->code);
    $this->assertEquals(Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode(), $client->getResponse()->getContent());


    /**
     * Create user with birthday good
     */
    $client     = $this->createClient();

    $randomName = rand(1000, 999999);

    $client->request(
        'POST',
        $url,
        array(),
        array(),
        Error::$header,
        '{
            "email":"test3+'.$randomName.'@Test.com",
            "password":"'.$password.'",
            "gender":"m",
            "firstName":"Test",
            "lastName":"'.$randomName.'",
            "image":null,
            "address":null,
            "enabled":1,
            "locked":0,
            "role":["ROLE_ANDROID"],
            "content":"Une description complète sur cette personne",
            "birthday":"1991-06-12",
            "facebookId":null,
            "avatar":null,
            "phone":"0601020304",
            "profession":"Robot",
            "iHostWith":null
        }'
    );

    $object = json_decode($client->getResponse()->getContent(), false);

    $this->assertNotNull($object);
    $this->assertTrue(is_object($object));
    $this->assertEquals($randomName, $object->lastName);
    $this->assertEquals(Response::HTTP_OK, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode(), $client->getResponse()->getContent());


    /**
     * Create user with password with min letters
     */
    $client     = $this->createClient();

    $randomName = rand(1000, 999999);

    $client->request(
        'POST',
        $url,
        array(),
        array(),
        Error::$header,
        '{
            "email":"test3+'.$randomName.'@Test.com",
            "password":"12345",
            "gender":"m",
            "firstName":"Test",
            "lastName":"'.$randomName.'",
            "image":null,
            "address":null,
            "enabled":1,
            "locked":0,
            "role":["ROLE_ANDROID"],
            "content":"Une description complète sur cette personne",
            "birthday":"1991-06-12",
            "facebookId":null,
            "avatar":null,
            "phone":"0601020304",
            "profession":"Robot",
            "iHostWith":null
        }'
    );

    $object = json_decode($client->getResponse()->getContent(), false);

    $this->assertEquals(Error::USER_PASSWORD_TOO_SHORT, $object->code);
    $this->assertEquals(Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode(), $client->getResponse()->getContent());
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public function createApplication()
{
    $app = new Application();

    require __DIR__.'/../../../app/config/dev.php';
    require __DIR__.'/../../../app/app.php';
    require __DIR__.'/../../../app/routes.php';

    // Generate raw exceptions instead of HTML pages if errors occur
    ExceptionHandler::register(false);
    // Simulate sessions for testing
    $app['session.test']            = true;
    // Enable anonymous access to admin zone
    $app['security.access_rules']   = array();

    return $app;
}

/**
 * Provides all valid application URLs.
 *
 * @return array The list of all valid application URLs.
 */
public function provideUrls()
{
    return [
        array('/users/')
    ];
}
}
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding this part: "which regroups all of a sudden or should it separate?" What did you mean by that?

Answer (score 1):

You should follow the [Single Responsibility Principle (SRP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

- Each class has to solve exact one issue. Same applies for `methods`/`functions`

  - In your case your Test class creates an application and does unit tests
  - Further you have one test method which tests multiply cases.

So, rather create multiply test methods such as:

- testRegisterUserUsingInvalidBirthdate
- testRegisterUserWithCompleteData

You include an autoloader in the test class. `require_once __DIR__.'/../../../vendor/autoload.php';` From UnitTests I am aware of a bootstrap file. If such a class exists/can be registered for functional tests as well you should move it to a respective file.